# Unable to use runserver_plus for django

Tags: python, django, https, django-manage.py, django-extensions

I am using the command ***"python3 manage.py runserver_plus 0.0.0.0:9999 --cert-file /path/to/cert/app"*** to run my python-django project on https but I get the below error

***File "/Users/xyz/django_dev_portal/django-api-1/app/manage.py", line 16
) from exc
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax***

I have django-extensions installed. Im unable to figure out whats going wrong as Im very new to Django and Python.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Python Version : 3.7.2

Cheers,
Sheetal

Comment: Which Python version are you using?

Comment: probably you need to activate your virtual environment.

Comment: Python Version 3.7.2. Edited the post

Comment: Not using Virtual env